# Google Sheets - Delete Row After One Year

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I apologise in advance, I'm new at using script with google sheets and after checking for an applicable script for my issue I can't seem to get any of them to work correctly for the sheet I'm working on. Im attempting to replace a paper document that our plant supervisors have for each of their employees. The plant workers have a points based attendance system where infractions drop off one year from the date of infraction.

Ideally the row would delete on its expiration date, thusly removing the points from the employee's total sum. If anyone would care to lend me a hand I would be more than grateful, thanks in advance.
[image: A general idea of what I'm going for]

Answer (score 0):

get all values of D1:O13,

check if today > expirDate,

if true, skip the line,

otherwise push the row into result array.

At last, set the results back to the sheet.

```
function removeExpired() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("D1:O13");
  const values = range.getValues();
  const hearders = values.shift();
  const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  const results = [hearders];
  for (const row of values) {
    const expireDate = new Date(row[2]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    const expired = today > expireDate;
    if (expired) continue;
    results.push(row);
  }
  range.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```